# Alternative to Chicken of the VNC

Tags: vnc

I need to VNC into a remote Debian server from my Mac to use Remote Console via an iLO-integrated Java Integrated Remote Console (IRC). I use Chicken of the VNC for that purpose. Is there any other open-source alternatives available? Thanks.

Comment: why people don't like questions, is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow. Questions about stuff other than programming are off topic on Stack Overflow. But you should have been signposted to Serverfault rather than downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "NoMachine" or "chrome remote desktop". it is not open-source products - free licence.

NoMachine - https://www.nomachine.com/

CRD - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

or you can use PORT forwarding from Linux to iLO IP. connect to Linux from MAC via ssh with tunnel and open iLO from MAC browser